# Mapping on Cauchy Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How can I show that $f(x)=x^2$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences?

That is the function preserves the Cauchy property.

Comment: This is trivial if each Cauchy sequence is convergent, because then it sends this sequence to a convergent sequence due to continuity. So is the function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ or something non-complete?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Irrelevant. Any Cauchy sequence lives in a bounded set.

Comment: @TedShifrin : I just now realized... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a fact that a sequence in $\mathbb R$ is Cauchy iff it is convergent.
Now if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence then it is a convergent sequence.
Therefore $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}=(x_n^2)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a convergent and so a Cauchy sequence.
Note that if this is a homework maybe this is not the correct way to prove it. It depents on what you have been taught.

Comment: No it's not a homework question, but the question asked is intended to be applied to show that if ${x_n}$ is Cauchy, and {${f(x_n)}$} is Cauchy, then $f$ is not necessarily uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\left(a_{n}\right)$ be a Cauchy-sequence. Then it is bounded so that $\forall n\;\left|a_{n}\right|<c$
for some constant. Then $\left|a_{n}^{2}-a_{m}^{2}\right|=\left|a_{n}+a_{m}\right|\times\left|a_{n}-a_{m}\right|\leq2c\times\left|a_{n}-a_{m}\right|$.

Comment: You don't need convergence, only boundedness. And any Cauchy sequence is bounded, so this argument works.

Comment: @StefanH I hope coffeemath is right...:-) Slightly adapted answer.

Comment: For boundedness: Pick $N$ so for $m,n\ge N$ we have $|a_m-a_n|<1$ Then if $A=\max(|a_k|:k\le N)$ we have $|a_i| \le A+1$ for all $i$ using triangle inequality.

Comment: @coffeemath I am fully convinced.